# c++11 template metaprogramming - Declaring a Type Trait at compilation time (switch like case)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I am tryng to implement a class selector, the function of this class is to select a specific trait of a class at compilation time. But I getting buggy Another requirement is that no static function has to be implement. My experience in metaprogramming is to low.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


template<class OptionSelected>
struct ContainnerValue
{
    typedef OptionSelected selectedValue;
    typename selectedValue value;
};

////Enum definition
enum class EOptions
{
    Option_One,
    Option_two
};
////trait base definition
template<EOptions>
struct SelectorClass{};

template<>
struct SelectorClass<EOptions::Option_One>
{
    void printClass()
    {
        std::cout<<"Class Selection One"<<std::endl;
    }
};
typedef SelectorClass<EOptions::Option_One> Option_One;

template<>
struct SelectorClass<EOptions::Option_two>
{
   void printClass()
    {
        std::cout<<"Class Selection two"<<std::endl;
    }
};

typedef struct SelectorClass<EOptions::Option_two> Option_Two;

int main(void)
{
    ContainnerValue<Option_One>::value.printClass();
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typename selectedValue` <- the `typename` keyword is only required when you're referring to a nested type (something with a `::`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: `selectedValue value;` is not a static data member; yet, you're trying to refer to it as if it were a static data member here: `ContainnerValue<Option_One>::value.printClass();`

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is a quite complex way to do what you want to do, but anyway, here's the minimal set of changes to make this work: change the following lines

```
typename selectedValue value;

void printClass()

ContainnerValue<Option_One>::value.printClass();
```

to

```
typedef selectedValue value;

static void printClass()

ContainnerValue<Option_One>::value::printClass();
```

That is, make `printClass` a `static` member function, and call it using the name of the class followed by `::`, without an object.

Comment: i have already try to attemp that way, but i cannot achieve any result.

Comment: So, what is the problem exactly? You could edit your question to add new information.